# A workaround to using an async operation inside setState

Tags: flutter

I have an async operation, the result of which should rebuild a widget.

The `setState()` doc says that

> The provided callback is immediately called synchronously. It must not
>   return a future (the callback cannot be async), since then it would be
>   unclear when the state was actually being set

So I had a simple workaround which meets my purpose but I am not sure if this is the right approach.

```
// awaiting for an async operation
distanceFromCenter = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(
  selectedLocation.latitude,
  selectedLocation.longitude,
  ReferencePoint.latitude,
  ReferencePoint.longitude);
setState(() {
// A colleague might not know why we're calling the setState() here
});
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: what is your original problem? what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: @pskink. Putting calculations  which changes the state inside setState() explicitly tells us we need to rebuild the widget because the state changed. Here(see the edit), we have a setState() which doesn't convey a colleague why exactly we are rebuilding the widget.. Perhaps, we can use comments. but I feel that is not the right way or is it?

Comment: @pskink In the above case, I wish to  calculate `distanceFromCenter` inside the `setState()` but I can't do it because it is an `async` function. I guess this clearly mention my intent.

Comment: ok if you **really** need to put `distanceFromCenter` iniside the callback then use `var distance = await ....; setState(() {distanceFromCenter = distance;})`

Comment: @pskink Oh okay! Then perhaps use a comment to let colleagues know why we're calling the setState(). Okay ! I take it.